# android.widget.ListView is not a view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

Im trying to get some data from bbdd with this method

```
/**********************************************************************
 * * Obten todos los nombres
 * 
 */

public Cursor getNombres(){


       Cursor respuesta = db.rawQuery("select "+TABLE_ROW_ID+","+CNOMBRE+" from "+TABLE_NAME, null);

       return respuesta;
}
```

in this class

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
     //Creamos la instancia de DataBaseHelper, un cursor y aplicamos el metodo getNombres al cursor.
     ayudabbdd = new DataBaseHelper(this);
     Cursor nombresC;     
     nombresC = (Cursor) ayudabbdd.getNombres();  
     startManagingCursor(nombresC);

     //Mientras el cursor no este vacio rellenamos la lista con el adaptador, que nos sirve para conectar unos datos con el listview.
     if(nombresC!=null){
     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listatab, nombresC, new String[] { "nombre" }, new int[] { R.id.lista });
     this.setListAdapter(adapter);
     this.getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
     }



     }
```

But log cat return me that

```
android.widget.ListView is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter
```

But in some tutorials this is the way to get an array from a bbdd and they don't have problem

Comment: of course,
         <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lista" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"></ListView>
     </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the doc for [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29), the constructor, which by the way is deprecated, gets as 5th parameter the ids of TextViews, from the doc:

```
to->    The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. 
These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are 
given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter. 
Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
```

Instead you are giving the id of lista, which is a ListView. Try to change using this:

```
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 };
...
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listatab, nombresC, new String[] { "nombre" }, to);
```

En plus, if your activity extends ListActivity, the ListView in your xml must have this id:

```
android:id="@android:id/android:list"
```

Take a look to this [example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/).

Comment: Im using api level8 (2.2) if i use theses constructor say me The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, Cursor, String[], int[], int) is undefined

Comment: Perfect. then The new constructor is only for new android versions?

Comment: There are 5 parameters. You make the mistake on the last one, you need to pass an id of a TextView not an id of a ListView, I added stuff to my answer, en plus you need to change the id of the list view

Comment: I also added a link to a full example using SimpleCursorAdapter. Hope it will help!