# AppCompatSpinner is not a view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I'm totally new to Android development, and I'm trying to populate a spinner with data from a database column. I am successful in populating the cursor object with the data, but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

I read about similar problems in other topics here, but nothing that really solved my issue.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_grade);

    AssetDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new AssetDatabaseHelper(getBaseContext(), "myDB");
    try {
        dbHelper.importIfNotExist();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name AS _id from Items",null);        
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.activity_set_grade,
            cursor,
            fromCols,
            toViews,
            0);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.items_spinner);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.id.items_spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My activity_set_grade contains this spinner (in a RelativeLayout if that matters):

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/items_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I get the following error message in my Logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424731/android-widget-listview-is-not-a-view-that-can-be-bounds-by-this-simplecursorada ... and yeah ... it is the same problem ... problem is with: R.layout.activity_set_grade, fromCols, toViews

Comment: As i said in my question I have already read all these other topics but they didn't help me. Maybe it's because I misunderstood something, or because the problem is different. I don't know! I don't think I deserve I down vote because of it

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* ... as i wrote without information about this 3 stuff question is off-topic ... **edit:** also `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.id.items_spinner);` ?id?really?not layout?????? please, read the doc ...

Comment: .... about: *As i said in my question I have already read all these other topics* .... you know that *I read about similar problems in other topics here, but nothing that really solved my issue.* **is meaningless**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're importing from the Android framework `SimpleCursorSpinner` but, because you're using the library stuff, you must use the `SimpleCursorSpinner` from the library too.

That is a simple change on your import from:

```
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter
```